# What is the difference between chicken cubes and ground chicken?

Tags: chicken

I need to order from a menu where both chicken cubes and ground chicken are choices. What's the difference?

Answer (score 6):

Ground chicken (or any other [ground meat](https://www.google.com/search?q=ground+meat&tbm=isch)) has been ground with a grinder. It can be formed into patties (like hamburgers), balls (like meatballs), sausage and so on, but [if cooked](https://www.google.com/search?q=cooked%20ground%20meat&tbm=isch) as-is will tend to turn into crumbles.

Cubes are, well, meat cut up into cubes: chunks of whole meat, with the original texture.